# Chartjs does not show on pdf in yii2 despite showing in html view

Tags: yii2, chart.js, mpdf

I have developed an app using Yii2, mpdf and chartjs. The page works well in html but doesn't show the chart when I export to pdf using mpdf. How can I solve this?

```
    <?= ChartJs::widget([
'type' => 'line',
'options' => [
    'height' => 400,
    'width' => 400,
    'show_as_html'=> true
],
'data' => [
    'labels' => ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    'datasets' => [
        [
            'label' => "Sales",
            'backgroundColor' => "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
            'borderColor' => "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            'pointBackgroundColor' => "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            'pointBorderColor' => "#fff",
            'pointHoverBackgroundColor' => "#fff",
            'pointHoverBorderColor' => "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            'data' => [28, 48, 40, 19, 96, 27, 100]
        ]
    ]
]
]);
?>
```

Comment: well there is a way around to add them but the code you provided does not describe how you are exporting the chart to pdf using mpdf you should provide the relevant code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see in the MPDF docs: https://mpdf.github.io/html-support/html-tags.html
that `canvas` and `script` tags are not supported. in the case of charts, most use canvas, you can see that chartsjs also uses canvas to render its charts. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html

Most PDF generator does not support rich HTML and charts.

I suggest you use `phantomJS` for generating pdf.

http://phantomjs.org/

http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/

for PDF: http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/4.0/3-usage/#output-to-pdf